# "Starting audio failed" error appears when requesting a GetUserMedia audio access

Tags: audio-recording, firefox-os, getusermedia

I am working on firefox os app that use audio  capturing .But I getting "Starting audio failed" error after sharing my microphone in Zte Open(firefox 1.4.0.0-prerelease). Here is my code

```
navigator.mozGetUserMedia({audio: true}, function(localMediaStream) 
{
visualize(localMediaStream);
}, function(err) {
console.log(err);
});
```

Also I added permission to manifest file

```
"audio-capture": {
        "description" : "Used to access mic"
    }
```

Comment: Can you try a later version? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Developer_phone_guide/ZTE_OPEN_C

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried in 2.0 but same error

Comment: Can you try this example to see if it works for you: https://github.com/mdn/voice-change-o-matic

Comment: "getUserMedia supported." app.js:93
"The following gUM error occured: Starting audio failed" app.js:117
Showing same error.

Comment: Are you getting the update from ZTE site?

Comment: No... There is no update for zte open  from zte side.